# Book about boy and girl who received super human genes from ancient human (possibly Adam)

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of a book that came out 10 or 15 years ago. The plot involved a boy and girl who both received super human genes in early childhood from an ancient human or alien. Possibly Adam.

They developed super intelligence/strength/accelerated healing abilities among other Mary Sue-esque traits.

They eventually escape Earth before it is destroyed on a ship the boy built. The girl specializes in medicine. They fall in love.

The book ends with them traveling in search of a new planet to live on.